French movie about teacher having an affair
In this French movie, a teacher who is married receives a love letter from a mysterious lover.  She is bored/upset with her husband, so she finally decides to meet him and they make love (the girl is blindfolded). Later, she discovers that the mystery man is actually her husband!
The movie I think was released between 2009 and 2012 (I'm not sure) and the guy was a bit psychic. He was her husband and they use to fight often.
Also in another scene in the movie a couple visit their house where they dance by changing partners and later guy and wife start fighting (by words).
One more scene I remember that the mystrey man used to request her to wear specific sexy outfits for college coming via her letter and she use to think that the mystery guy is one
of her students, but later towards the end her husband tells her that he used to send those letters.

Do you remember how old this movie is?

I remember a plot similar like this one, but from what I remember, the man was some kind of an agent. Does it sounds familiar?

the movie i think released b/w 2009 nd 2012(i m not sure)     and the guy was a bit psychic he was her husband and they use to fight often

also in another scene in movie a couple visit their house where they dance by changing partners and later guy and wife star fighting(by words)

1 more scene i remember is she use to think that the mystery man is from her class as he use to request her to wear sexy outfits bby the letter

@Yogesh: Could you update your question with these new details?

@Larme:I updated but its asking to review the edit & i dont know how to do it + i dont think i have 1k reputation


if you know the movie but you think the language is not french then please tell because i am not 100% sure about it being french,though i saw it in french and it did look french


Thank you for helping 
i got it
the name of the movie is  Le zèbre (1992) 
sorry for any time wastage

Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.
